# Backbone: Why are events syntax quite different between model and view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

### define events in Backbone.Model

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.on('change', function(){
        console.log('- Values for this model have changed.');
    });
  }
})
```

### define events in Backbone.View

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: "document-row",
  events: {
    "click .icon":          "open",
    "click .button.delete": "destroy"
  }
})
```

### My Question

define events syntax are quite different between model/collection and view, why are they designed in that way?

I think it's better to define model event like this. But backbone don't support it.

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  events: {
    "change": "foo"
  },

  foo: function(){
    console.log("test")
  }
});
```

Comment: I do not know about the design choice. But if in case, you want to define `events` in `model` as done in `views` you can basically do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/jdpxgd8s/3/). It's just a rough example not a complete solution.

Comment: It's not that the syntax for defining events is different, but rather that there is no *"special"* (syntactic sugar) syntax for defining events on models. The syntax you are using on your model works just as well in a view or collection (since your really just binding the event directly). Further it doesn't really do the same thing since in a view your are delegating the events to the root `el`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate type of events: `Backbone.Events` and jQuery DOM events - so making these look the same seems like a bad idea as it would make code confusing not to mention it wouldn't actually work because the View UI events need different info: `'<eventName> <optional DOM selector>: <methodName>'` whereas normal internal events have a different syntax.

`Backbone.Events` follows the typical "publish/subscribe" pattern - it's just a way for apps to internally say "Something has happened" via `.trigger` and "I want to know when something happens" via `.on` or `.once` and the equivalent which you would use in a View because it handles cleaning up the listen when the view is removed: `.listenTo` and `.listenToOnce`.

So in your example the `"change"` event in the model is an internal event which Backbone fires when an attribute changes. The `"change"` in the View is jQuery DOM event (actually a delegate event) and you could optionally listen to something deeper in the view `"change .myinput"` so they are not equivalent.

The other difference is that `.trigger` can pass any arguments it likes after the first one (the event name), whereas the View event passes the DOM event object which you don't control e.g. `onChange: function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); }`.